# Sprite doesn't move! XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make a space invaders-like game and i've found some difficulties tho,
my main player sprite moves correctly according to the keyboard, but not the Banjo!
Can you help?

**Game1.CS**

```
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
  {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;



    public float displayWidth;
    float displayHeight;
    float overScanPercentage = 10.0f;
    float minDisplayX;
    float maxDisplayX;
    float minDisplayY;
    float maxDisplayY;
    player accordian;
    baseSprite background;
    PlainBanjo Banjo;

    float getPercentage(float percentage, float inputValue)
    {
        return (inputValue * percentage) / 100;
    }
    private void setScreenSizes()
    {
        displayWidth = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        displayHeight = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
        float xOverscanMargin = getPercentage(overScanPercentage, displayWidth) / 2.0f;
        float yOverscanMargin = getPercentage(overScanPercentage, displayHeight) / 2.0f;

        minDisplayX = xOverscanMargin;
        minDisplayY = yOverscanMargin;

        maxDisplayX = displayWidth - xOverscanMargin;
        maxDisplayY = displayHeight - yOverscanMargin;
    }
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
   public void update_accordian()
    {


        accordian.SpriteRectangle.X = (int)accordian.X;
        accordian.SpriteRectangle.Y = (int)accordian.Y;


        KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            accordian.X = accordian.X + 2;
        } if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            accordian.X = accordian.X - 2;
        }

      }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        displayWidth = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        setScreenSizes();
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        accordian = new player(Content.Load<Texture2D>("accordian"), new Rectangle(350, 433,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width / 10,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height / 10));
        accordian.X = 400;
        accordian.Y = 400;
        background = new baseSprite(Content.Load<Texture2D>("background"), new Rectangle(0, 0,
            Window.ClientBounds.Width,
            Window.ClientBounds.Height));
        Banjo = new PlainBanjo(Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlainBanjo"), new Rectangle(0,0,50,50));

       Banjo.setupSprite( 0.05f, 200.0f, 200, 100, true);
        //  accordian.setupSprite();
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        update_accordian();
        Banjo.Update(maxDisplayX, minDisplayY, minDisplayX,maxDisplayY);
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        background.Draw(spriteBatch);
        accordian.Draw(spriteBatch);
        Banjo.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}`
```

**baseSprite**

```
 class baseSprite : Game1
{
       public Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0, 0);
        public Texture2D SpriteTexture;
        public Rectangle SpriteRectangle;
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float XSpeed;
        public float YSpeed;
        public float WidthFactor;
        float TicksToCrossScreen;
        public bool Visible;       


    public void setupSprite(                  
        float widthFactor,
        float ticksToCrossScreen,
        float initialX,
        float initialY,
        bool initialVisibility)
    {
        WidthFactor = widthFactor;
        TicksToCrossScreen = ticksToCrossScreen;
        SpriteRectangle.Width = (int)((displayWidth * widthFactor) + 25f);
        float aspectRatio =
            (float)SpriteTexture.Width / SpriteTexture.Height;
        SpriteRectangle.Height =
            (int)((SpriteRectangle.Width / aspectRatio) + 25f);
        X = initialX;
        Y = initialY;
        XSpeed = displayWidth / ticksToCrossScreen;
        YSpeed = XSpeed;
        Visible = initialVisibility;
    }


   public void LoadTexture(Texture2D inSpriteTexture)
    {
        SpriteTexture = inSpriteTexture;
    }

    public void SetRectangle(Rectangle inSpriteRectangle)
    {
        SpriteRectangle = inSpriteRectangle;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteTexture, SpriteRectangle, Color.White);
    }
    public baseSprite(Texture2D inSpriteTexture, Rectangle inRectangle)
    {
        SpriteTexture = inSpriteTexture;
        SpriteRectangle = inRectangle;
    }


}
```

**player.cs**

```
  class player : baseSprite
{
    public player(Texture2D inSpriteTexture, Rectangle inRectangle)
        : base(inSpriteTexture, inRectangle)
    {

    }
}
```

**PlainBanjo.cs**

```
 class PlainBanjo : baseSprite
{

     public PlainBanjo(Texture2D inSpriteTexture, Rectangle inRectangle)
        : base(inSpriteTexture, inRectangle)
    {

    }

     public void Update(float maxDisplayX, float minDisplayY, float minDisplayX,float maxDisplayY)
     {

         X = X + XSpeed;
         SpriteRectangle.X = (int)(X + 0.5f);
         SpriteRectangle.Y = (int)(Y + 0.5f);

         if (X + SpriteRectangle.Width >= maxDisplayX)
         {
             XSpeed = Math.Abs(XSpeed) * -1;
             Y += 10;
         }

         if (X <= minDisplayX)
         {
             XSpeed = Math.Abs(XSpeed);
         }
         if (Y + SpriteRectangle.Height >= maxDisplayY)
         {
             YSpeed = Math.Abs(YSpeed) * -1;



         }
         if (Y <= minDisplayY)
         {
             YSpeed = Math.Abs(YSpeed);
         }


     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calculating the new value of accordian but never actually updating accordian.SpriteRectangle.X and accordian.SpriteRectangle.Y with the new accordian values.